# Looping over lists using purrr::map producing error

Tags: r, purrr

#### Problem

I have a list of historical tax rates and a vector of taxable incomes that I need to combine in order to calculate tax liabilities for each income level, in each year. When I go to iterate over the historical tax rates and incomes, I get an error message:

```
Error: Argument 2 can't be a list containing data frames
```

Interested in any advice about how I might modify the data or function call (below) to complete the iteration.

#### Data

```
pit_sch <- list(`2016` = structure(list(id = c("2016", "2016", "2016", "2016"
), hh_exp_def = c(0.989, 0.989, 0.989, 0.989), `Taxable income` = c("$18,201 – $37,000", 
"$37,001 – $80,000", "$80,001 – $180,000", "$180,001 and over"
), `Tax on this income` = c("19c for each $1 over $18200", "$3572 plus 32.5c for each $1 over $37000", 
"$17547 plus 37c for each $1 over $80000", "$54547 plus 45c for each $1 over $180000"
), cumm_tax_amt = c(0, 3572, 17547, 54547), tax_rate = c(19, 
32.5, 37, 45), threshold = c(18200, 37000, 80000, 180000), real_threshold = c(18402.4266936299, 
37411.5267947422, 80889.7876643074, 182002.022244692), real_cumm_tax_amt = c(0, 
3611.72901921132, 17742.16380182, 55153.6905965622)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L)), `2017` = structure(list(
    id = c("2017", "2017", "2017", "2017"), hh_exp_def = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1), `Taxable income` = c("$18,201 – $37,000", "$37,001 – $87,000", 
    "$87,001 – $180,000", "$180,001 and over"), `Tax on this income` = c("19c for each $1 over $18200", 
    "$3572 plus 32.5c for each $1 over $37000", "$19822 plus 37c for each $1 over $87000", 
    "$54232 plus 45c for each $1 over $180000"), cumm_tax_amt = c(0, 
    3572, 19822, 54232), tax_rate = c(19, 32.5, 37, 45), threshold = c(18200, 
    37000, 87000, 180000), real_threshold = c(18200, 37000, 87000, 
    180000), real_cumm_tax_amt = c(0, 3572, 19822, 54232)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L)))

income <- seq(from = 1, to = 100000, by = 100)
```

#### Attempt

```
# Defining the function which will calculate tax liability for a given set of tax rates (in pit_sch) and income
nominial_tax_calc <- function(data, income) {
  i <-pmax(which(income >= data[, 7]))
  if (length(i) > 0) 
    return(tibble(income = income, 
                  tax = (income - data[i, 7]) * (data[i, 6] / 100) + data[i, 5]))
  else
    return(tibble(income = income, tax = 0))
}

# Function that results in the error
map(pit_sch,~map_df(income, nominial_tax_calc, data = .))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need two changes in your function,

1) Instead of `pmax` use `max`

2) wrap `as.numeric` in the `tax` calculation

```
nominial_tax_calc <- function(data, income) {
   i <- max(which(income >= data[, 7]))
   if (length(i) > 0) 
     return(tibble(income = income, 
        tax = as.numeric((income - data[i, 7]) * (data[i, 6] / 100) + data[i, 5])))
    else
      return(tibble(income = income, tax = 0))
}
```

and then call

```
library(purrr)
map(pit_sch,~map_df(income, nominial_tax_calc, data = .))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `data` argument is a tibble, but you are using bracket indexing as if it were a base R data frame.  This has the effect of leaving a column name in, which is causing your trouble:

```
pit_sch[["2016"]][2, 7]

# A tibble: 1 x 1
  threshold
      <dbl>
1     37000
```

Convert `data` to a data frame in the first line of `nominial_tax_calc()`,
with `data <- as.data.frame(data)`, and then you can use the indexing syntax you've chosen, and your function will run without error.